# Не удаётся открыть источник файл <duckx/duckx.hpp>

Tags: cmake, библиотеки, cmakelists

VS 2022 не может открыть <duckx/duckx.hpp>. Код ошибки Е1696 и С1083 "Не удаётся открыть файл включения: duckx/duckx.hpp...".
Использую СМаке. В главвной папке CMakeList.txt:

```
# CMakeList.txt: файл проекта CMake верхнего уровня; проведите глобальную конфигурацию
# и включите сюда подпроекты.
cmake_minimum_required (VERSION 3.8)

# Включение горячей перезагрузки для компиляторов MSVC, если поддерживается.
if (POLICY CMP0141)
  cmake_policy(SET CMP0141 NEW)
  set(CMAKE_MSVC_DEBUG_INFORMATION_FORMAT "$<IF:$<AND:$<C_COMPILER_ID:MSVC>,$<CXX_COMPILER_ID:MSVC>>,$<$<CONFIG:Debug,RelWithDebInfo>:EditAndContinue>,$<$<CONFIG:Debug,RelWithDebInfo>:ProgramDatabase>>")
endif()
project ("Docx")
FILE(COPY "./Docx/res/test.docx" DESTINATION "${CMAKE_BINARY_DIR}/Docx/res")


# Включите подпроекты.
add_subdirectory("${CMAKE_SOURCE_DIR}/include/DuckX")
find_package(duckx)
add_subdirectory ("Docx")
```

CMakeLists.txt в Docx

```
# CMakeList.txt: проект CMake для CMakeProject1; включите исходный код и определения,
# укажите здесь логику для конкретного проекта.
#

# Добавьте источник в исполняемый файл этого проекта.
add_executable (Docx "CMakeProject1.cpp" "CMakeProject1.h")
target_link_libraries(Docx PUBLIC duckx::duckx)

if (CMAKE_VERSION VERSION_GREATER 3.12)
  set_property(TARGET Docx PROPERTY CXX_STANDARD 20)
endif()

# TODO: Добавьте тесты и целевые объекты, если это необходимо.
```

Не знаю что делать.

П.С. Может быть это очень очевидно, но только начал